# Is there any disadvantage/risk when using a software licensed to someone else?

Tags: hacker-experience

Some of my softwares are glowing red because they are licensed to another player. Does it matter? What does it even do?

Can the owner of the license track his software back to me or anything like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only risk is when downloading the software. Make sur that you erase the log file after you downloaded the software, otherwise he will be able to track you. There are absolutly no risks in using the software.

The way the game works is very similar to real life. You cannot track someone if he has a license on a product. The only way to track someone online is with its IP address, just like in the game.

Comment: Most keys from todays games cannot be used twice.